# Cmake check if the current platform is Fedora

Tags: linux, build, cmake, fedora

I am trying to create custom cmake commands for `Fedora Linux`
So far I have custom rules for `Apple Osx` now I want to have fedora specific rules.

```
if(APPLE or FEDORA)
  message("This is apple or fedora")
else()
  message("This is other platfor")
endif()
```

How can I check if the current platform is Fedora?

Comment: (That said, those answers should be updated to use `/etc/os-release` for modern versions of most Linux distros.)

Comment: @mattdm well yeah this is one solution of the problem perosnally I used `/etc/fedora-release` file to solve the case but the approch with `/etc/os-release` is better